# How to Develop different Styles Combobox in Visual Studio Express for Window phone?

Tags: windows-phone

How to Develop different Styles Combobox in Visual Studio Express for Window phone? 
When Click on combobox by default it take blue color.I want to change the color when click on it.How to set different styles of combobox in expressin blend?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a ComboBox for Windows Phone 7 development. Instead you should use a ListPicker from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)

The listpicker looks like this:

[image: Small]

or like this

[image: Big]

Comment: But in our project it is must to add Combobox.but I am unable to set back ground color of combobox when click on combobox it take default color.plz send me solution for that.

Comment: No, you must NOT , and I repeat, MUST NOT, use a ComboBox. Using a ComboBox on WP7 is wrong in all possible ways. Stop making the users want you hate you before you even started.

Comment: @claus Totally agree.. Combobox and scrollers - not for Metro UI

Comment: It's in the said framework I linked. Comes fully loaded with examples and documentation.

Comment: can u send one more tim eI am unable to open it.

Comment: My apologies, SO overwrote the link when I uploaded the images. The link is here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/ (and I corrected the post)

Comment: Can u plz send me some link on WEB services?what is it ,why it is use and how to use it in Window phone 7 developnemt applications.

Comment: The toolkit download comes with documentation and examples. I'm sure that should be more than enough for you.