# How to develop ListPicker in Window phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to develop ListPicker in Window phone 7? Which namespace we have to add and which refereces?

Comment: Dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826447/how-to-develop-different-styles-combobox-in-visual-studio-express-for-window-phon/6826475 Where you already been answered. Can't you read a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The ListPicker is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 very good articles on using the ListPicker at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx

and

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth